# access XML Content <a14:sharpenSoften> for image Blur using Python Docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am planning to search the specific heading in the document, and then i have to strike out all the contents in that heading. The document has many headings, each heading may have paragraph, tables, images altogether or in any combinations.

I have installed docx, i was able to search the specific heading, strike out paragraph, tables.

Now next task to the access the images under that Heading and blur those images (instead of strikeout, we are planning to blur the image)

I am able to get the resource id for the images which is under Specific Heading by using the code in the link [Bluring the Image which is under specific Heading using Python docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47347505/bluring-the-image-which-is-under-specific-heading-using-python-docx)

Since there are no direct API supporting this features, I am trying to use the XML code as referenced in https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/55#issuecomment-43914055..

I am having the XML Code without blur and with blur (by manually setting the Artistic Effect (for blur) of Image)

XML Code for the Image without blur:

```
<pic:blipFill>
  <a:blip r:embed="rId11">
    <a:extLst>
      <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
        <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
      </a:ext>
    </a:extLst>
  </a:blip>
  <a:srcRect/>
  <a:stretch>
    <a:fillRect/>
  </a:stretch>
</pic:blipFill>`
```

XML Code for the image with blur:

```
<pic:blipFill>
  <a:blip r:embed="rId11">
    <a:extLst>
      <a:ext uri="{BEBA8EAE-BF5A-486C-A8C5-ECC9F3942E4B}">
        <a14:imgProps xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main">
          <a14:imgLayer r:embed="rId12">
            <a14:imgEffect>
              <a14:sharpenSoften amount="-50000"/>
            </a14:imgEffect>
          </a14:imgLayer>
        </a14:imgProps>
      </a:ext>
      <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
        <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
      </a:ext>
    </a:extLst>
  </a:blip>
  <a:srcRect/>
  <a:stretch>
    <a:fillRect/>
  </a:stretch>
</pic:blipFill>
```

From the above codes with and without blur, it is clear that the following code is the only difference between them

```
<a14:imgProps xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main">
  <a14:imgLayer r:embed="rId12">
    <a14:imgEffect>
      <a14:sharpenSoften amount="-50000"/>
    </a14:imgEffect>
  </a14:imgLayer>
</a14:imgProps>
```

I am able to access the tag till "a:ext", see below code

```
trans = r.xpath('.//w:drawing/wp:inline/a:graphic/a:graphicData/'
                'pic:pic/pic:blipFill/a:blip/a:extLst/a:ext')
```

and trans is returning the parameter

```
<CT_PositiveSize2D '<a:ext>' at 0x4535db8>
```

If i am trying to access the next level tag "a14:imgProps" after "a:ext", it is throwing the following error

File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\xmlchemy.py", line 751, in xpath
    xpath_str, namespaces=nsmap

File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 1589, in lxml.etree._Element.xpath (src\lxml\etree.c:61221)

File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 307, in lxml.etree.XPathElementEvaluator.**call** (src\lxml\etree.c:178760)

File "src\lxml\xpath.pxi", line 227, in lxml.etree._XPathEvaluatorBase._handle_result (src\lxml\etree.c:177712)

XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix

Since i thought accessing the parameter "a14:sharpenSoften" will be helpful to blur the image. But i dont know how to access this parameter.

Can any one help me to access the parameter "a14:sharpenSoften" OR if there is any other method to blur the image which is under specific heading, paragraph or tables, let me know about it.

Note: I am using Python docx module and Python 2.7

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. "How can I access the parameter?" <- what does that mean even? Just edit the XML if you want different value.

Comment: As stated by @M.Prokhorov this question is very vague, and we do not know what you wish to achieve please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and edit your question to clarify and include [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will give us a better idea of what you are trying to achieve and what you have attempted so far.

Comment: I have edited the questions, can you please check it now and let me know if you need any further information

Comment: The error message is very clear. *"XPathEvalError: Undefined namespace prefix"*. You need to declare the `a14` prefix before you use it. Should not be too hard, you have declared the other prefixes as well, after all

Comment: Your failure to indent the XML makes this question unnecessarily difficult to read and may have led to your mistake of leaving out the enclosing `<a:ext>` element around the `a14:imgProps` element in question. In future, please take the time to make your listings readable with proper indentation. I have edited the question to indent the XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can overcome this error by adding the following lines before calling `r.xpath()`:

```
import docx
docx.oxml.ns.nsmap['a:14'] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main"
```

Then this code will allow you to set the `a14:sharpenSoften` attribute:

```
xpath_str = (
    './/w:drawing/wp:inline/a:graphic/a:graphicData/pic:pic/pic:blipFill'
    '/a:blip/a:extLst/a:ext/a14:imgProps/a14:imgLayer/a14:imgEffect/a14:'
    'sharpenSoften'
)
sharpenSoftens = r.xpath(xpath_str)
if not sharpenSoftens:  # then that element is not found
    return
sharpenSoften = sharpenSoftens[0]
sharpenSoften.set('amount', '-50000')
```

Comment: I am able to navigate till the path

trans = r.xpath(                           './/w:drawing/wp:inline/a:graphic/a:graphicData/'                           'pic:pic/pic:blipFill/a:blip/a:extLst/a:ext/a14:imgProps/a14:imgLayer/a14:imgEffect/a14:sharpenSoften')  

Can you tell how to set the value amount="-50000"

it may be very basic, but im new to python and xml

Comment: I've added example code to my answer. Don't neglect to vote up this answer if it is helpful and accept it if it answers your question.

Comment: It is throwing an error "IndexError: list index out of range" for the code sharpenSoften = sharpenSoftens[0]

Comment: It sounds like you left out the test for whether `r.xpath()` actually returned any items, the line `if not sharpenSoftens: return`. This code won't add such an element, only retrieve one that is already there.

Comment: Yes, i didnt add those lines earlier. Now i have added these lines, since if condition is satisfied, "return" is executed. actually, the sharpenSoftens is printing []. is there any way to set the value "sharpenSoften.set('amount', '-50000')"

Comment: I suspect you need to add the whole `<a:ext>` subtree containing the `sharpenSoften`. Search Google with "python-pptx workaround function" for more information on adding elements.